# BigQuery : is it possible to iterate over an array?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to iterate over an array in bigquery in standard sql?

Basically declare an array of strings representing table fields. ex :

```
DECLARE FIELDS_TO_CHECK ARRAY<STRING>;
SET FIELDS_TO_CHECK =  ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ];
```

and then iterate on this array to create requests getting percentage of non null value on this field :

```
select count(FIELD) / count(*) from 
'table_name'`
```

Comment: If you are storing the column names as strings, then you need to do this at the application level.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL
I am using here TEMP TABLE `table_name` to mimic your data with some simplistic dummy data, but you can just remove that CREATE statement and use your own table

```
#standardSQL
DECLARE FIELDS_TO_CHECK ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE `table_name` AS 
  SELECT 1 field1, NULL field2, 3 field3, 4 field4, 5 field5 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, 3, NULL, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 3, 4, 6;

CREATE TEMP TABLE result(field STRING, percentage FLOAT64);  
  
SET FIELDS_TO_CHECK =  ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ];

LOOP
  SET i = i + 1;
  IF i > ARRAY_LENGTH(FIELDS_TO_CHECK) THEN 
    LEAVE; 
  END IF;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    INSERT result
    SELECT "''' || FIELDS_TO_CHECK[ORDINAL(i)] || '''", COUNT(''' || FIELDS_TO_CHECK[ORDINAL(i)] || ''') / COUNT(*) FROM `table_name`
  ''';

END LOOP; 

SELECT * FROM result;
```

Above example returns below output

```
Row field   percentage   
1   field2  0.0  
2   field1  0.66666666666666663  
3   field3  1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use for in to loop through array elements.
The key point is to use UNNEST to fetch element inside array.
The sentence would be a little bit more declarative than use loop with index moving.

```sql
DECLARE FIELDS_TO_CHECK ARRAY<STRING>;
SET FIELDS_TO_CHECK =  ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ];

FOR field IN
  (SELECT * from UNNEST(FIELDS_TO_CHECK))
DO
  # do whatever you want with field
END FOR
```

Comment: When I put "SELECT field;" inside the do statement first it is printing the entire array and then one element at a time. How can I get only the singular elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
  LOOP
   SET i = i + 1;
    IF i > ARRAY_LENGTH(FIELDS_TO_CHECK) THEN 
      LEAVE; 
    END IF;

   SET field= FIELDS_TO_CHECK [ORDINAL(i)];

   # do whatever you want with field

   SELECT field ;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?